# Php - When I require, it gives me a browsing error

Tags: php

I have an input in a html file, wich as its form action on swag.php

```
<?php
header ('Location: ./teste.php');
$varr = $_POST['amount1'] ;

?>
```

I have teste.php

```
<?php 
require 'swag.php';

echo $var2;
?>
```

And then the input:

```
<form action="./post_swag/swag.php" method="post">
<input name="amount1" type="text" size="12" maxlength="4" />

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I insert the input's value, it gives me a browsig error, in teste.php, saying that it can't redirect me to the page because firefox detected that the server is rederecting a request to this adress for that the process is never concluded.
And then it says that might be disabled cookies...
What should I do?

Comment: It looks like `swag.php` redirects to `teste.php`, which requires `swag.php`. Seems a bit recursive. Is that right?

Comment: its an infinite loop of redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Location` header tells the browser to stop what it's doing and load something else instead. So you have this:

1. browser requests `swag.php`
2. `swag.php` sends `Location` header telling the browser to load `teste.php`.
3. `teste.php` loads `swag.php`, which sends the `Location` header telling the browser to load `teste.php`
4. Repeat step 3 *ad infinitum*.

Firefox is detecting this infinite loop of redirects and says "I can't do that".

Comment: hahahah of course!! How could I did'nt notice that :P

Thanks a lot!!

How do I make a header repeating only once?

Comment: Well, in this case, don't `require` the code that sends the redirect in the code that you're redirecting to. More generally, it's not clear  why you have the redirect at all - why not just have one of those PHP files handle the form submission?